# Magento m2e pro post-update troubles

Tags: magento, m2e

i'm using magento 1.7.2 CE and m2epro 6.0.8 , updated for 6.1.4  and have got troubles with Create Orders from Ebay

**1 Problem:**

Magento Order was not created.

> Reason: The requested Payment Method is not available.

Found  FAQ Hint, that says :

> You should enable payment method “M2E Pro Payment”
> in System→Configuration→Payment Methods

i've checked this setting, ***it IS enabled***,  don't  know what else i can do.
Payments done on Ebay are PayPal, there were no changes of setting after update

however i can confirm the order manually, but then i have another Problem with Double VAT calculation, that doesn't appear on automatic order creation.

FAQ says, Double VAT are only created if Catalog Prices are set Excluding VAT, but ***my Magento manages Prices including VAT***, so dont how else to avoid double VAT

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today. In my case it was caused by the module `RicoNeitzel_PaymentFilter`. I had to activate the *"M2E Pro Payment"* - method for all customer groups.